# ReactStrap: DropDown items appear transparent on phone

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I have this dropDown menu that works perfectly on desktop:
[image]
But, on phone it's transparent for some reason:
[image]

This is the code that implements it:

```
<UncontrolledDropdown>
                <DropdownToggle
                  aria-expanded={false}
                  aria-haspopup={true}
                  caret
                  color="danger"
                  data-toggle="dropdown"
                  href="#pablo"
                  id="dropdownMenuButton"
                  nav
                  onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  role="button"
                >
                  {this.state.category == "" ? "category" : this.state.category}
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu
                  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
                  className="dropdown-danger"
                >
                  {categoryDropDownItemsNames.map((categoryDropDownName) => (
                    <DropdownItem
                      tag="span"
                      name="category"
                      value={categoryDropDownName}
                      // onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                      onClick={this.onCategoryChosen}
                    >
                      {categoryDropDownName}
                    </DropdownItem>
                  ))}
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: hi, interesting, does it happen when you emulate mobile in chrome?

Comment: Yes. I tested it both on emulator and on my real phone

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with the template I'm using. Anyway, here's how I fixed it:

```
 <DropdownItem
                      tag="span"
                      name="category"
                      value={categoryDropDownName}
                      onClick={this.onCategoryChosen}
                      /** I need to force this style, otherwise it'll appear transparent on mobile */
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(256, 256, 256, 1)",
                      }}
                    >
                      {categoryDropDownName}
                    </DropdownItem>
```